# how to retrieve all data from firebase and display on listview android?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android app ,which is get order from customers,but i faced a problem . I am trying to Retrieve Data from Firebase and display in a list view. I can get the data back from Firebase but when it displays in the listview it just displays one data in many times. I want to be displayed on one line for each record. Can anyone see where i am going wrong??
[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ymhm.png)

[ListView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhBAZ.png)

**OrderHistory**

```
public class OrderHistory
{
    String ammount,photoId,trxId,name,copy,photoSize,date;
    public OrderHistory(String name,String photoId,String trxId,String copy,String photoSize,String ammount,String date)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.ammount = ammount;
        this.photoId = photoId;
        this.copy = copy;
        this.photoSize = photoSize;
        this.trxId = trxId;
        this.date = date;
    }


    public String getAmmount() {
        return ammount;
    }

    public void setAmmount(String ammount) {
        this.ammount = ammount;
    }

    public String getPhotoId() {
        return photoId;
    }

    public void setPhotoId(String photoId) {
        this.photoId = photoId;
    }

    public String getTrxId() {
        return trxId;
    }

    public void setTrxId(String trxId) {
        this.trxId = trxId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCopy() {
        return copy;
    }

    public void setCopy(String copy) {
        this.copy = copy;
    }

    public String getPhotoSize() {
        return photoSize;
    }

    public void setPhotoSize(String photoSize) {
        this.photoSize = photoSize;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**OrderHistoryAdapter**

```
public class OrderHistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<OrderHistory> orderHistories;
    Context context;

    public OrderHistoryAdapter(Context context, List<OrderHistory> myOrderInformations) {
        this.context = context;
        this.orderHistories = myOrderInformations;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return orderHistories.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return orderHistories.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_my_order_history, parent, false);
        final TextView txtName, txtdate, txtPhotoId, trxId,txtAmount,txtPhotoSize,txtCopy;
        txtName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtdate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtPhotoId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtPhotoId);
        trxId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTrx);
        txtAmount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
        txtPhotoSize = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSize);
        txtCopy = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCopy);
        txtName.setText(orderHistories.get(position).getName());
        txtdate.setText(orderHistories.get(position).getDate());
        txtPhotoId.setText(orderHistories.get(position).getPhotoId());
        trxId.setText(orderHistories.get(position).getTrxId());
        txtAmount.setText(orderHistories.get(position).getAmmount());
        txtCopy.setText(orderHistories.get(position).getCopy());
        txtPhotoSize.setText(orderHistories.get(position).getPhotoSize());
        return view;
    }
}
```

**OrderHistoryList**

```
public class OrderHistoryList extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private List<OrderHistory> orderHistories;
    private static String phoneNumber;
    private ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_my_order);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        getAllOrderFromFirebase();
    }

    private void getAllOrderFromFirebase()
    {
        orderHistories = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("order");
        String phone = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phone");
        databaseReference.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String amount, photoId, trxId, name, copy, photoSize, date;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    photoId = snapshot.child("photoId").getValue(String.class);
                    amount = snapshot.child("totalAmount").getValue(String.class);
                    trxId = snapshot.child("trxId").getValue(String.class);
                    photoSize = snapshot.child("photoSize").getValue(String.class);
                    date = snapshot.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                    copy = snapshot.child("totalCopy").getValue(String.class);
                    orderHistories.add(new OrderHistory(name, photoId, trxId, copy, photoSize, amount, date));
                }
                OrderHistoryAdapter adapter;
                adapter = new OrderHistoryAdapter(OrderHistoryList.this, orderHistories);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data try this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959536/how-to-retrieve-all-the-keys-in-firebase-android/46960211?noredirect=1#comment80869654_46960211 have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is by the way you refer to your data so instead of this

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("order");
```

use this

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("order");
```

and you didn't use a query object to query your database reference

so now you don't query directly from databaseReference like the way you did it

instead you do this:

```
Query query=databaseReference.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone);
```

once you have a query that fits you now add on child listener and continue the rest of your code:

```
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

 //the rest of your code goes here(on child added/changed/......)

)};
```